# Is there any cleaner way to check if tuple or row are meet a condition in a database using mysql connector?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I am using `mysql.connector` in Python to manage particular database, I am trying to check in a table if there is any tuple or row that meet a condition, here is the code:

```
db_campaign = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="pass",
    database="campaign"
)

cursor = db_campaign.cursor()
query = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE id = 10)"
cursor.execute(query)
for val in cursor:
    if val[0] == 1:
        found = True
```

Is there any way to make this cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor = db_campaign.cursor()
query = "SELECT 1 FROM transaction WHERE id = 10)"
cursor.execute(query)
return cursor.fetchone() is not Non
```

You can also test `len(cursor.fetchall())`